# Python graph- change axis marker colours and legend border colours

Tags: python, graph, colors, border, axes

I'm using Python to plot a couple of graphs and I'm trying to change the formatting and essentially 'brand' the graph. I've managed to change most things using pylab.rcParams[...], but I can't work out how to change the colour of the markers on the axes and the border around the legend. Any help would be much appreciated. The line below is an example of the type of code I've been using to edit other parts. Basically just lines taken from matplotlibrc, but I can't find them to change everything I want.

```
pylab.rcParams[axes.labelcolor' = '#031F73'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to use `rcParams`, the proper parameters are `xticks.color` and `yticks.color`.  I can't seem to find a key for the legend frame color.  You can set that (along with the tick colors) programmatically though.

```
import pylab

pylab.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6], label ='test')
lg = pylab.legend()
lg.get_frame().set_edgecolor('blue')
ax = pylab.axes()

for line in ax.yaxis.get_ticklines():
    line.set_color('blue')
for line in ax.xaxis.get_ticklines():
    line.set_color('blue')

for label in ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_color('blue')
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_color('blue')

pylab.show()
```

Comment: That's great. The one thing left is that the scale (100, 200 etc) is still black. For some reason I think I thought this would change with the ticks, but thinking about it now that doesn't seem sensical. Anyway, thank you for your response and if you could answer that one bit more I would be very grateful.

Comment: Ok. Now I'm working with large numbers, so there's a +1.30934e9 as a scale under the axis and it's showing up in black. How would I change this? Is there any way of just having one overarching change to the plot such that these little things aren't an issue and everything will change to a certain colour?

Comment: I found a convenience function that avoids having to go through the loops above.  You can just call `ax.tick_params(colors='blue')`.  That still doesn't fix your problem with the scale, though.